# Hide critical data in template based on user access level

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I have a `Item` model, where `Item` objects can either be `public` (accessible to all users) or `private` (accessible only to authenticated users):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_public = models.BoleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #...
    secret_key = ...

    class Meta:
        # I need to keep items in order:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)
```

What I need is to list *all* items using a `generic.ListView` - keeping the order - but **hide the `secret_key`** of those items with `is_public=False` for anonymous users.

So in the template, I *hide* the `secret_key` if the user is not authenticated, like:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>{{ item.title }} - {{ item.secret_key }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>{{ item.title }} - This item is private. Sign up to see the secret_key!</p>
{% endif %}
```

and the `ListView` is like:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
```

I'm aware that I can send two *separate* querysets for non logged-in users to the template, one for *public* items and the other for *private* ones; but I'm not sure how can I **keep the order** (`'-created_at'`) in this approach.

The question is:

1. Is it *safe* to send all the `secret_keys` to the template and *hide* them for non logged-in users there?
2. (if it is safe, then) Is there a **more efficient** way of doing this?

I tried overriding the `get_queryset` method of my `ItemListView` and move the `if` condition from template to there (I think this would increase the performance, right?). I handled the situation where the users is authenticated (simply return all the objects); but for non logged-in users, I thought about somehow joining two separate querysets, one holding the *public* items and the other holding *only* the `title` and `created_at` of *private* items; but I didn't find to keep the order in this approach:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Item.objects.all()
        else:
            # ???
```

This was only a minimal-reproducible-example; Actually in the  project, I have multiple `access_levels`; Each user has an `access_level`, based on their `plan` (e.g. basic, normal, pro, etc.) and each `Item` has an `access_level`; And an  I'm dealing with about **+100K** objects, fetched from different databases (`postgresql` - some cached on `redis`) so the performance *really* matters here. Also the system is up-and-running now; so I prefer **less fundamental** solutions.

Thanks for your time. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If template is render at server side (and Django template does), then it is safe isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to send all the secret_keys to the template and hide them for non logged-in users there?

Your template is rendered server-side, and the client only get the rendered markup, so yes, it is totally safe. Well, unless someone in your team messes with the template code of course ;-)

> (if it is safe, then) Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Just filter the queryset in your view - you don't need two distinct querysets, and filtering the queryset will not change it's ordering.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ItemListView, self).get_queryset()  
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        qs = qs.filter(is_private=False) 
    return qs
```

and in your template:

```
{# avoids doing the same constant lookup within the loop #}
{% with is_auth=request.user.is_authenticated %}
{# I assume the queryset is named "objects" in the context ?#}
{% for item in objects %} 
    <p>{{ item.title }}{% if is_auth %} - {{ item.secret_key }}{% endif %}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

EDIT: bdoubleu rightly mentions in his answer that his solution makes testing easier. If you only need fields from your model (no method call), you can also [use QuerySet.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) instead:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ItemListView, self).get_queryset()  
    fields = ["title", "created_at"]
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        fields.append("secret_key")
    else:
        qs = qs.filter(is_private=False) 

    return qs.values(*fields)
```

This will also make your code a bit more efficient since it doesn't have to build full model instances.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to annotate the queryset to add an extra attribute for `display_secret_key` which is going to be more efficient than checking the user access level for each item in the queryset while templating.

```
from django.db.models import F, Value as V

class ItemListView(ListView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        annotations = {
            'display_secret_key': V('')
        }
        if self.request.user.access_level == 'PRO':
            annotations['display_secret_key'] = F('secret_key')
        return (
            super().get_queryset()
            .annotate(**annotations)
        )
```

Then in your template:

```
<p>{{ item.title }} - {{ item.display_secret_key }}</p>
```

Comment: Ain't that a bit complicated ? Also it's bordering on mixing domain with presentation...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers fair enough, maybe the `Concat` isn't necessary but an annotated attribute on a queryset is at least testable based on the different access levels. The alternative is testing the template which is much more difficult in terms of application and legibility.

Comment: Mmm, you do have a point here indeed... Not that testing templates is THAT difficult (assuming proper markup), but it's more of a burden to maintain. This being said, you could just use a `ValueQueryset` and exclude the private_key field for anonymous users...

Comment: This being said, you can get the same result (wrt/ testability) using `QuerySet.values()` - if you don't need to invoke any model model / property etc in the template of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 Templates, one for the authenticated user one for the unauthenticated. (just overwrite the  get_template_names() for authentication check  and add something like _sectempl.html to the found name and add the appropriate copy of the template with the secret data)

But I would say with bruno desthuilliers that if you switched off the debug mode there could be no constellation where unauthenticated users see content within

```
{% with authenticated=request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {% if authenticated %}
    do secret stuff 
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

or

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
   hide secret stuff for all the others
{% endif %}
```

If you got a complex user-grouping-combination outside the standard django user right management (where you could [ask for user-permissions in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions)) then I would write the user_status (your "plan" or accesslevel) into the user-session (while authentication) and check for this user_status in the output-function of the attribute of the object.

**Sketch:**
Use in template:

```
   {% for i in object_list %}
     {{ i.name}}, {{ i.print_secret }}
   {% endfor %}
```

In the model you create a "print_secret"-method witch returns the secret according to the previous recorded  user_status in the session-data.